# Is there any Jenkins API to retrieve PMD/ findbugs, checkstyle results

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, findbugs, pmd, jenkins-api

I have a requirement to retrieve Findbugs, PMD and checkstyle reports using API.
FindBugs: bug report can be extracted from findbug.xml 

 Is there any other option other than extracting report from xml files?

### Update: Answer

As @Andrew said, 
You can find findbugs result json by appending `/api/json` to jenkins results:

> `http://<jenkins-host:port>/job/<your_job_name>/<build_id>/7/findbugsResult/api/json?depth=2`
> `http://<jenkins-host:port>/job/<your_job_name>/<build_id>/7/pmdResult/api/json?depth=2`
> `http://<jenkins-host:port>/job/<your_job_name>/<build_id>/7/checkstyleResult/api/json?depth=2`

If you want only numbers use `/api/json?depth=0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins REST API exposes the information on many of the key pages as json by adding the suffix /api/json.

The relevant plugins that publish these type of results to the dashboard are the [Warnings](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin) and [Static Code Analysis plugins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Static+Code+Analysis+Plug-ins), both written by  Ulli Hafner

The Warnings Plugin (since release 4.49) seem to support retrieving result information via the Jenkins Restful interface.  Have a read of the conversation [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26113).

Comment: It gives me individual results. Since all these are static analyses, can't we get them in a single call?